# Loading a multidimensional array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm finishing up work on a Java assignment (a "Delivery Schedule" program) and hit a bit of a stumbling block. 
The first component of this project which I completed is to make a class that makes Delivery objects, based on user-inputted attributes. That portion works completely. The second class is the Scheduler class, which allows a user to manipulate data within an array of 20 objects in order to create an ordered "schedule" of deliveries to be made. Some are user-inputted values as created from the delivery class, but my professor wants us to have the first 4 portions of the Delivery array of objects to be entered manually. This is where I'm making a mistake -

```
Delivery[][][][][] dArray=new Delivery[20][20][20][20][20];


Delivery[][][][][] dArray={"Mar",4,17,30,"Pizza"},{"Apr",1,6,30"Special Delivery"},{"May",6,12,0,"Amazon (Books)"},{"Jun",3,11,15,"Car Parts"};
```

That code is in the data area of the Schedule class. Please help! I can't do the rest of the Schedule class if this portion doesn't work.

For easier reading, these are the objects I need to put into the array:

```
Mar 4, 17:30 Pizza

Apr 1, 06:30 Special Delivery

May 6, 12:00 Amazon (Books)

Jun 3, 11:15 Car Parts
```

Where "Mar", 4, 17,30, and "Pizza" are all separate values. 4,17,30 are int values.

**Edit**: From the comments of this question.

Structure of Delivery class from this [`link`](http://pastebin.com/jtGLaBpJ).

```
public class Delivery {
    private String month ="";
    private int day=0;
    private int hour=0;
    private int minute=0;
    private String message=""; //no longer than 40char
    private int maxd=0;

    //getter setter and other methods
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Delivery[][][][][]? This will creat 5 dimensional array, which I don't think you want.

Comment: What is the structure of `Delivery` class?

Comment: @NamanGala can you help me figure out a better way to format it? My intro to java prof didn't do a very good job on arrays, so I have a really bad understanding of arrays. http://pastebin.com/jtGLaBpJ This is my Delivery class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're creating a five-dimensional array, as @NamanGala pointed out in the comments.

What you probably want to do is create a one-dimensional array of type `Delivery`, and have each instance of `Delivery` hold the attributes.

```
Delivery[] myDeliveries = new Delivery[20];
myDeliveries[0] = new Delivery();
myDeliveries[1] = new Delivery();
```

Also, the object literal syntax you're using doesn't work in Java. You must invoke the Delivery object's constructor. Looking at the Delivery class you linked to above, you could do something like this:

```
myDeliveries[0] = new Delivery("Mar", 4, 17, 30, "Pizza");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm having an issue though where after I put the attributes in the instances, it's giving me a "] expected" error.
Delivery[] dArray=new Delivery[20];
        dArray[0]={"Mar",4,17,30,"Pizza"}; 
        dArray[1]={"Apr",1,6,30,"Special Delivery"};
        dArray[2]={"May",6,12,0,"Amazon (Books)"};
        dArray[3]={"Jun",3,11,15,"Car Parts"};

Comment: I'm new to this site so I'm not entirely sure why the code won't display on a new line - sorry for the mess :<

Comment: I formatted it using the new delivery objects instead of trying to "load" the array, and now it works! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you want to use arrays in this case, it that the requirement. 
You can create a Java POJO class and handle these as objects.

Comment: My professor requires an array for the project. I have different ways that I would have handled it, but that's because I hate arrays.